# Tag for body definiton in composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I am creating a composite component to use it in my application. I need to define for every composite component its own body. When I used JSP few years ago, I specified custom body in some tag file, for example titlebar.tag and future body was declared by tag below:

```
    <jsp:doBody />
```

and I used it in JSP file:

```
<foo:titlebar>
    <jsp:body>
        something
    </jsp:body>
</foo:titlebar>
```

now I need to have something similar in JSF composite components between cc:implementation

```
<cc:implementation> 
    SOME TAG FOR FUTURE BODY DECLARATION
</cc:implementation>
```

Can you give me an advice please?

Comment: I fixed some severe terminology mistakes in your question. To learn the difference between "custom components" and "composite components" and "tag files", head to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There the [`<cc:insertChildren>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/insertChildren.html) is for.

```
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <cc:insertChildren />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Chapter 8.5: Composite Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets005.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC... i am really stupid because everything is in documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html